# Accessing template-based controls in UserControl from parent page

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms, user-controls

Before I start, I am **not** asking how to access a server-side control hosted within a UserControl from the parent page.  That's been asked many times, and this is not a duplicate of that.

This question is about server-side controls placed within a **template** item of a UserControl instance.

---

In ASP.NET I have a [UserControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) with multiple template handlers, which results in an HTML block being rendered with a **single instance** of each template (it is not like a `<asp:Repeater>` where a template is used multiple times).  For example:

```
<uc1:MyUserControl runat="server" ID="myCtrl1">
  <TopControls>
    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litTop" />
  </TopControls>
  <BottomControls>
    <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnBottom" />
  </BottomControls>
</uc1:MyUserControl>
```

And the UserControl is set up something like...

```
<div class="myUserControl">
  <div class="topControls">
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="plhTopControls" />
  </div>
  <div class="bottomControls">
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="plhBottomControls" />
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that in order for the **parent page** to access the controls, it's necessary for me to have a method in the UserControl to find them:

```
Public Overrides Function FindControl(id As String) As System.Web.UI.Control
    Dim ctrl As Control = Nothing
    If Not TopControlsContainer Is Nothing Then
        ctrl = TopControlsContainer.FindControl(id)
    End If
    If ctrl Is Nothing AndAlso Not BottomControlsContainer Is Nothing Then
        ctrl = BottomControlsContainer.FindControl(id)
    End If
    If ctrl Is Nothing Then
        ctrl = MyBase.FindControl(id)
    End If
    Return ctrl
End Function
```

This is because the Visual Studio 2015 designer no longer sees the two server-side controls as belonging to the page, but instead the controls belong to the UserControl, and so I have to specifically declare them in the page and set them up in the `Page_Load`:

```
Protected WithEvents litTop as Literal
Protected WithEvents btnBottom as Button

litTop = myCtrl1.FindControl("litTop")
btnBottom = myCtrls.FindControl("btnBottom")
```

**Is it possible** to set up the UserControl so that the server-side controls within the templates are picked up by the designer file for the parent page, so I don't have to go through this each time I add a new UserControl or server-side control within that UserControl?

If it is not possible with a UserControl, is it possible to do it with a server-side control?  (If so, what attributes are required for that?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MyUserControl.ascx.vb, decorate the ITemplate properties with [TemplateInstanceAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.templateinstanceattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), specifying [TemplateInstance.Single](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.templateinstance(v=vs.110).aspx). (The default is Multiple.) From the documentation:

> A single instance of a template allows you to reference controls that are contained within the template.

VB.NET:

```vb
<PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)>
<TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single)>
Public Property TopControls As ITemplate

<PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)>
<TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single)>
Public Property BottomControls as ITemplate
```

C#:

```csharp
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
[TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single)]
public ITemplate TopControls { get; set; }

[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
[TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single)]
public ITemplate BottomControls { get; set; }
```

After you compile the code and re-save the parent page, the Visual Studio designer will generate backing fields for controls declared inside the templates.

**Note:** You should only specify TemplateInstance.Single if the template is instantiated exactly once.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying - this is superb, and solves my question exactly - thank you :-)  Do you also happen to know how to stop the `Content is not allowed between the opening and closing tags for element 'MyUserControl'` warning from showing?

Comment: Try adding the `<PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)>` attribute to both template properties (in addition to TemplateInstance).

Comment: You, sir, are a star - perfect - thanks :-)  I am unable to assign the bounty for another 19 hours, but be assured that it's yours

Comment: I realise this is a very cheeky request, but as you were kind enough to solve this issue, could you please [have a look at my latest one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44934396/usercontrol-with-templates-change-server-control-rendered-id)?