# UserControl with templates, change server-control rendered ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

**TL;DR...**

When creating a `[UserControl]` with single use templates, is it possible to get make server-side controls placed within those templates to render their `id` **without** the `UserControl` or container IDs?

---

In my ASP.NET web application I've create a `UserControl` with multiple single-use template (I've only given the code here for one of those templates)...

```
Public Class MyUserCtrl
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Private Class MyUserCtrlLiteralContainer
        Inherits Control
        Implements INamingContainer
    End Class

    <TemplateContainer(GetType(MyUserCtrlLiteralContainer)),
     TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single),
     PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)>
    Public Property FirstTemplate As ITemplate

    Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Init
        If FirstTemplate IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim container As New MyUserCtrlLiteralContainer()
            FirstTemplate.InstantiateIn(container)
            plhFirst.Controls.Add(container)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

(Note, `plhFirst` is a `<asp:PlaceHolder>` in the mark-up)

This is an example of the control being used in a page (controlled by a `Master` page)...

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="content" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContent">
  <uc1:MyUserCtrl runat="server" id="muc1">
    <FirstTemplate>
      <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnMyButton" />
    </FirstTemplate>
  </uc1:MyUserCtrl>
</asp:Content>
```

When the `<asp:Button>` is rendered to the HTML, the `id` of the element results in...

```
id="ctl00_content_muc1_ctl00_btnMyButton"
```

... where the second `ctl00` is the ID of the `MyUserCtrlLiteralContainer` instance.

---

**Is there any way** to make the `id` of the control render as follows?  (So the ID of the container is not used)

```
ctl00_content_muc1_btnMyButton
```

**Or even better, is there any way** to make the `id` of the control render as follows? (So neither the ID of the usercontrol or container is used)

```
ctl00_content_btnMyButton
```

**Alternatively, is there a different way to instantiate the controls in the `UserControl` that would result in either of the above?**

Comment: Do you need MyUserCtrlLiteralContainer? (That is, can you instead instantiate the template directly inside the placeholder?) And if you do need MyUserCtrlLiteralContainer, does it need to implement INamingContainer?

Comment: @MichaelLiu - thanks for your input again. You are correct in your assumption that there is no need for the extra `MyUserCtrlLiteralContainer`, and instead the properties can be setup with `TemplateContainer(GetType(INamingContainer))` and instantiated straight into the placeholder... that results in `ctl00_content_muc1_btnMyButton` which is a great step forward.  I feel that getting to `ctl00_content_btnMyButton` is probably a step too far, but if you have any ideas, fire away.  In the mean time, I suggest you create an answer with your suggestion so I can give you the credit you deserve

Comment: @MichaelLiu - Ah, one thing to note is that if you (by complete chance) have a control in the UserControl instance with the same name as the `<asp:PlaceHolder>` in the UserControl mark-up, it will complain about duplicate ID's - which is fair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button `id` includes `muc1` and `ctl00` because UserControl and MyUserCtrlLiteralContainer implement [INamingContainer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer(v=vs.110).aspx). If you don’t want the `id` to include those parts, but you *do* want the `id` to include other ancestor IDs, then you can’t use those control types.

**Removing `ctl00`:** Unless you specifically need a custom container control, you can delete MyUserCtrlLiteralContainer and just instantiate the template directly in the PlaceHolder.

**Removing `muc1`:** You must rewrite your UserControl as a server control that doesn't implement INamingContainer.

Here’s a sample implementation:

```vb
<ParseChildren(True)>
Public Class MyUserCtrl
    Inherits Control

    Private plhFirst As PlaceHolder

    <TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single),
     PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)>
    Public Property FirstTemplate As ITemplate

    Private Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Init
        plhFirst = New PlaceHolder()
        Controls.Add(plhFirst)

        If FirstTemplate IsNot Nothing Then
            FirstTemplate.InstantiateIn(plhFirst)
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Render(writer As HtmlTextWriter)
        ' <div class="myUserCtrl">
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "myUserCtrl")
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div)

        ' <div class="firstControls">
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "firstControls")
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div)

        plhFirst.RenderControl(writer)

        ' </div>
        writer.RenderEndTag()

        ' </div>
        writer.RenderEndTag()
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Note:** To avoid possible ID conflicts, I intentionally leave `plhFirst.ID` unset.

Comment: Once again, you are my personal hero - thank you @Michael - this exactly solves the problem.  I would have preferred to have quick and easy control over the HTML (by having actual mark-up rather than code) but this does just what I need it to... thank you again :-)

Comment: @freefaller: If you have a lot of static HTML, you can call `writer.Write("<big chunk of HTML>")` instead of AddAttribute and RenderBeginTag.

Comment: Nice thinking - yes, that works as well - thank you again :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you are going to be able to get the IDs to look as you wish because they were designed to show control hierarchy, ugly as they are.

You *can*, however use static IDs on a control, page, or entire project if you wish. Check out this handy ScottGu article from way back in 2010:

https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series

The section you'll be looking for is `Today’s Cleaner Markup Topic: Client IDs`

Comment: Thanks - I'm already aware of `ClientIDMode`, but as you have already stated it would not include the parent structure

Comment: you could fake it manually, though that sounds not fun at all